# Entity vs Value Object

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am trying to learn and apply DDD to a new project, so facing a question which may be something very basic, but I might have missed out.

Can a bounded context contain an entity as well as a value object for the same entity?

My question arises due to the reason that we generally need a ViewModel which is bound to keep the details which are closer to the View in addition to the Model data. But there are cases where a bounded context may use some entity as a referential object in a transaction.

For example, let us take a hypothetical case. Assume we have the Employee context where we have Employee entity and Department entity as well. We will have IDs for both the entities.

A Department may be created/updated etc., in this domain. We may then add employees to this departments as well.

Now when we display an employee, we would like to display some information about the department which may not need the entire Department Entity. We may need about 50% of the details in the department.

My question is, can we have another ValueObject for the department in such scenarios? Or would it break something?

If I don't do it, then I would be forced to create and some how hydrate the details of the Department at a lower level..

Does my thinking make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to clearly separate the domain model from UI concern.** In terms of your example, the department entity is a domain concept, whereas the department summary data that supports displaying an employee is clearly a UI artifact.

**The department entity**

- lives in the domain model
- may be used by different use cases on that model

**The department summary object**

- Exists only to support a specific view
- **Is not a value object** in the DDD sense
- **Does not live in the domain model**

So where should you put the department summary class? The summary class is an app service/UI concern, but the persistence mechanism probably needs it to provide data in a structured way on the repository interface (if you want to avoid repackaging objects).

**Try to put it near the app service, because this is where it logically belongs.** Depending on your architecture, you will need an object-to-object mapping to get the data from the repository into the summary objects.

Comment: hmm, think I am getting it. So it is better to keep independent view models and an additional service which fills back the data for the summary. But does it make sense to have that summary (in my case a scaled down version of the entity), as a value object (in addition to the entity)?

Comment: It is a value object structurally, but I recommend against making it a "normal" value object within your domain model, unless it really is a domain concept. Imagine you have five different summary classes, because you need five different views with varying detail. Now you would end up with 5+1 classes in your domain for the same domain concept!